# Use camera image or gallery image for custom sticker in whatsapp sticker pack application

Tags: android, android-studio, assets, whatsapp, whatsapp-stickers

I am working on a whatsapp sticker pack application. I am able to add static stickers from assets to whatsapp stickers following the [demo](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/master/Android)

I need to use local image (from camera or gallery) as sticker and add it to whatsapp stickers.

Any idea about it, how can i use local images for this?
Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want to change or add stickers in an existing app (sticke pack) which is already installed on a phone and is already plugged-into WhatsApp?!!

Answer (score 1):

After trying a lot of ways, finally i solved this problem.
The approach is to save a json file on device containing the list of StickerPacks.
You can follow the [this](https://github.com/idoideas/StickerMaker-for-Whatsapp) demo.

Comment: This is not really an answer and you are not linking to anything showing how or where and when to create or manipulate a json file. How are you related to the team of that app you are linking to please?

Comment: Did you find more tricks ? Like usually you cannot have more than one pack having same name but I saw an app have this. It seems he is creating new folder for each pack under one root folder.